# how to use boolean type column in Google calendar charts?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I want to depict build status (Pass or fail) using a boolean type(true/false) on google's Calendar type charts. I am using the below HTML code for the same. But I am getting a red flag prompting me to add 2 columns . Any suggestions what could be wrong in this snippet ?

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["calendar"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   function drawChart() {
       var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
       dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
       dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'boolean',id :'pass/fail', role:'certainty' }); 
       dataTable.addRows([
          [ new Date(2012, 3, 13), true ],
          [ new Date(2012, 3, 14), true ],
          [ new Date(2012, 3, 15), true ],
          [ new Date(2012, 3, 16), true ],
          [ new Date(2012, 3, 17), false ]
          // Many rows omitted for brevity.

        ]);

       var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));

       var options = {
         title: "Build Execution Analytics",
         height: 350,
       };

       chart.draw(dataTable, options);
   }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="calendar_basic" style="width: 1000px; height: 350px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each chart type has a specific [Data Format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar#data-format)

Calendar charts do not accept a `boolean` column

from the reference, allowed columns are...

**column 0**  -- `date`, `datetime`, or `timeofday`
**column 1**  -- `number`
**column n**  -- `string` -- `role: tooltip` *(optional)*

I would suggest using a certain number for `pass` and another for `fail`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id :'pass/fail' });
    dataTable.addRows([
      [ new Date(2012, 3, 13), 100 ],  // pass
      [ new Date(2012, 3, 14), 100 ],  // pass
      [ new Date(2012, 3, 15), 100 ],  // pass
      [ new Date(2012, 3, 16), 100 ],  // pass
      [ new Date(2012, 3, 17), 0 ]     // fail
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, {
      title: 'Build Execution Analytics',
      height: 350,
    });
  },
  packages:["calendar"]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="calendar_basic"></div>
```